# Adding workgroup user to SQL Server on another Workgroup machine

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, workgroup

We have 2 workgroup machines (say WG1 and WG2)

WG1 has SQL Server 2008 installed. and WG2 is web server.

I need to install application on WG2 server connecting to WG1 database server using Windows Authentication for database.

For doing so, i need to add user of WG2 server on SQL Server on WG1 server. But as the servers are in workggroup, from WG1 server i can't add user of WG2 server.

Is this possible? Can someone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling and R&D, finally came to conclusion that this is not possible. Main reason is in windows authentication we have username as 'domain name\username id'. So if we add same user (say user1) on both machines say WK1 and WK2, id for user1 in SQL will be different on WK1 and WK2.